# Is there a race in the following concurrent code

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

Let's say I have different implementations of an interface:

```
interface IDataManager
{
  Integer GetData(string key); // returns null if data is not found
  void UpdateData(string key, int value);
}
```

All implementations of this interface are properly synchronized.
Also, I have a class to query data that is stored inside `IDataManager` implementations:

```
public class DataProvider {
    private final List<IDataManager> dataManagers; // immutable, set from constructor

    public DataProvider(List<IDataManager> dataManagers) {
        this.dataManagers = dataManagers;
    }

    public List<Integer> getData(String key) {
        List<Integer> found = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataManagers.size(); i++) {
            IDataManager dataManager = dataManagers.get(i);
            Integer data = dataManager.getData();
            
            if (data != null) {
                found.add(data);
            }
        }

        return found;
    }
}
```

The caveat here is that while some threads execute `DataProvider.GetData()`, other threads might update individual `IDataManager` implementations using `IDataManager.UpdateData`. Each instance of `IDataManager` is synchronized properly, but the fact that they change individually concerns me.
Should I first acquire locks for all instances of `IDataManager` before iterating them (Let's say they provide such opportunity)?

I am asking because it reminds me of an example I saw in a book "Java concurrency in practice", Listing 4.10:

```
public class NumberRange {
 // INVARIANT: lower <= upper
 private final AtomicInteger lower = new AtomicInteger(0);
 private final AtomicInteger upper = new AtomicInteger(0);

 public void setLower(int i) {
    // Warning-- unsafe check-then-act
    if (i > upper.get())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("can’t set lower to " + i + " > upper");
    lower.set(i);
 }

 public void setUpper(int i) {
    // Warning-- unsafe check-then-act
    if (i < lower.get())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("can’t set upper to " + i + " < lower");
    upper.set(i);
 }

 public boolean isInRange(int i) {
    return (i >= lower.get() && i <= upper.get());
 }
}
```

Here, in method `isInRange` values of `lower` and `upper` are read independently, not together under a lock. It reminds me of my `DataProvider.GetData` method in the previous example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have added a "java" tag, hope it will help

Comment: It depends on the requirements. If the list of integers must accurately represent the data set at the time reading starts, you should make sure no updates can take place.

Comment: AtomicInteger.get/set (as its most methods) are "under lock"/"safe", please don't draw "correct conclusions" from "wrong premises"... ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Should I first acquire locks for all instances of IDataManager before iterating them (Let's say they provide such opportunity)?

It depends on your requirements.

Without acquiring the locks it's possible that `IDataManager.UpdateData()` in one thread changes data while `DataProvider.getData()` is iterating over `IDataManager`s in another thread.

With acquiring the locks `IDataManager.UpdateData()` and `DataProvider.getData()` act atomically.

Both options are fine: the 1st one has higher performance, the 2nd one gives stricter guarantees.

Specifically the 1st option allows this:

```java
IDataManager dm1 = ...;
IDataManager dm2 = ...;
DataProvider p = new DataProvider(List.of(dm1, dm2));

initialThread() {
  dm1.UpdateData("a", 10);
  dm2.UpdateData("a", 20);
}

void thread1() {
  dm1.UpdateData("a", 11);
  dm2.UpdateData("a", 22);
}

void thread2() {
  System.out.println(p.getData());
}
```

to output:

```
10,22
```

while the 2nd option does not allow that.